# django reverse url to the view for current view with current arguments

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I would like return from view the url of current view with given argument (pk)

I thought about using `reverse` or `PATH_INFO` from reqeust's meta.

1) Can I do the first soemhow smarter?

2) how safe (in terms of risk of being manipulate) is accesing the values from REQUEST?

```
ipdb> request.META['PATH_INFO']
u'/products/creative_deactivate/9/'
ipdb> reverse('products.views.creative_deactivate', kwargs={'pk':creative.pk})
'/products/creative_deactivate/9/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Request.get_full_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path):

```
request.get_full_path()
```